# ASP.NET Core Force timespan datatype to 24h Format on inputs

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

No matter what i do i cannot get my inputs to appear as 24h format for a timespan

```
    public class Horario
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]        
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [Display(Name = "Início")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{HH:mm}")]
        public TimeSpan Inicio { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{HH:mm}")]
        public TimeSpan Fim { get; set; }

    }
```

for some reason no matter what i write on the format string it renders it as 12h with AM/PM

```
        <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="form-group col-3">
                <label asp-for="Horario.Inicio" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Horario.Inicio" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Horario.Inicio" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3">
                <label asp-for="Horario.Fim" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Horario.Fim" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Horario.Fim" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `asp-for` on an input, and the backing property is a `TimeSpan`, then Razor renders that as an input with `type="time"`. The "time" input type is generally rendered as a browser control, and that browser control is going to be localized. The underlying value is 24 hour format (it actually won't even work if it's not, since it must be ISO), but if your device's culture is 12 hr, then that is how it will be shown. There is no way around that, as it's a browser control.

If you *really* don't want it displayed like that, then your only option is to just use a regular "text" input type via:

```
<input asp-for="Horario.Inicio" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Then, it will be just text (no browser control) and the straight value provided to the input will be displayed. However, you will lose any built-in validation and it of course will not be as easy for users to enter the time. They could make mistakes and put in values that are invalid. You can add your own validation rules via JS or even create your own custom JS input, but that's all on you.

Answer (score 0):

So to work around this issue, this is what i used

on the back end

```
    #region Properties
    [Required]
    [BindProperty]
    [RegularExpression("^(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$", ErrorMessage = "Insira uma hora no formato HH:MM")]
    public string Inicio { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [BindProperty]
    [RegularExpression("^(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$", ErrorMessage = "Insira uma hora no formato HH:MM")]
    public string Fim { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public Horario Horario { get; set; }
    #endregion


    #region Handlers
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        TimeSpan inicio;
        if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(Inicio, out inicio))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Hora de Início inválida.");
        }

        TimeSpan fim;
        if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(Fim, out fim))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Hora de Fim inválida.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _toastNotification.AddErrorToastMessage("Dados inválidos.");
            return Page();
        }


        Horario.Inicio = inicio;
        Horario.Fim = fim;
        _horarioService.Add(Horario);

        try
        {
            await _horarioService.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch(DbUpdateException e)
        {
            //This either returns an error string, or null if it can’t handle that error    
            var error = e;
            if (error != null)
            {
                // Log Error and notify user 
                _logger.LogError($@"Falha ao criar Horário para o UAP {Horario.Uap}\n Erro: {e.InnerException}");
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"O horário {Horario.Inicio}-{Horario.Fim} {Horario.Uap} já existe.");                    
                _toastNotification.AddWarningToastMessage($"O horário {Horario.Inicio}-{Horario.Fim} {Horario.Uap} já existe.");
                return Page(); //return the error string
            }
            throw; //couldn’t handle that error, so rethrow
        }

        // Notify user action was successful and log information
        _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Horário adicionado.");
        _logger.LogInformation($@"Adicionado Horário {Horario.Inicio}-{Horario.Fim} {Horario.Uap}. Data: {DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm")}");

        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
    #endregion
```

and on the front end

```
        <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="form-group col-3">

                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend date">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='Inicio' asp-for="Inicio" />

                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Inicio" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-3">

                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend date">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='Fim' asp-for="Fim" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Fim" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
```

and im using bootstrap datetimepicker

```
@section Scripts{

@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
<script src="~/lib/moment.js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/limonte-sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<script>

    function OnSubmit() {
        $form = $('#form');
        if ($form.valid()) {
            $(".submit-overlay").fadeIn();
            $form.find(':submit').attr('disabled', true).html('<span class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> A processar...');
        }
    }

    $(function () {

        $('#Inicio').datetimepicker({
            icons: {
                time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                date: "fa fa-calendar",
                up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
                next: "fa fa-arrow-right",
                previous: "fa fa-arrow-left",
            },
            format: 'HH:mm'
        });

        $('#Fim').datetimepicker({
            icons: {
                time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                date: "fa fa-calendar",
                up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
                next: "fa fa-arrow-right",
                previous: "fa fa-arrow-left",
            },
            format: 'HH:mm'
        });
    });

</script>
```

this solves validation and any culture issues with browsers plus a decent UI for the user.